# Value inside if statement returning undefined out of scope

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i am trying to use​ `xval` when `currentQuestionIndex`​ is not equal to two but it is returning as undefined, since it is not satisfying the condition. How do i store the variable inside the if statement to be used when the if condition does not met.

```
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    var xval = currentscore;
 }
```

Can you please figure out solution, it is done in java script

Answer (score 1):

Either assign a default variable before the `if`:

```
var xval = 0;
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    xval = currentScore;
}
```

or use an `else` clause:

```
var xval;
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    xval = currentScore;
} else {
    xval = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . My main objective is to store the currentScore value when currentQuestionIndex ==2 and use the same x Val value outside the if statement when currentQuestionIndex not equal to 2. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. The scope of the variable is the whole function, so if you don't reassign `xval` it will have the old value. But if you haven't initialized it yet, it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a varibale `xval` with in the body of `if` condition.Hence, a local variable takes place.So, if the condition is not satisfied and you are going to access the `xval` variable it will returning as `undefined`.

**Try something like this :**

Declare a variable globally.

```
var xval = '';
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
  xval = currentScore;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . My main objective is to store the currentScore value when currentQuestionIndex ==2 and use the same x Val value outside the if statement when currentQuestionIndex not equal to 2. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: You can access that with the same code. If `currentQuestionIndex == 2` returns true then xval is updated with the currentScore value.

Comment: Will Xval remain same when currentQuestionindex equal to 5??? Imagine current score value changes with currentQuestionindex

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9chho4vs0FS3BaSFZvaU1lc1E                                        .Here in this file  i am trying to reference x value in if(currentQuestionindex == 5 && currentScore = xvalue).    It is saying xvalue is out of scope and not executing if condition.